# Adding a space between kanji

Tags: spacing, mactex, japanese

I am using CJK successfully on MacTeX thus:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newenvironment{Japanese}{%
  \CJKfamily{min}%
  \CJKtilde
  \CJKnospace}{}
\begin{document}

\title{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}\begin{Japanese}講道館 柔道 \end{Japanese}\end{CJK}}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the output does not maintain the space between 講道館 and 柔道.  What should I do to preserve it?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i can't answer your question, but have a question for you ... did you intentionally omit backslashes before your control sequences, or did you cut-and-paste from a text that used a different character than a backslash, or were backslashes removed "automatically" when this was posted?  i'm asking, because there have been some problems on this site in the handling of backslashes.

Comment: As it stands, the example cannot be run, please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `\CJKnospace`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newenvironment{Japanese}{%
  \CJKfamily{min}%
  \CJKtilde
%  \CJKnospace
}{}
\begin{document}

\title{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}\begin{Japanese}講道館 柔道 \end{Japanese}\end{CJK}}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that was embarrassingly easy